# Graceful exit when closing console window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to make a graceful exit from a console app when the close button is hit.

```
bool done = false;

BOOL ctrl_handler(DWORD event)
{
    if (event == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT) {
        done = true;
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler((PHANDLER_ROUTINE)(ctrl_handler), TRUE);

    while (!done)
        do_stuff();

    cleanup();
    cout << "bye";
}
```

My handler gets called properly but the main thread does not resume afterwards so the "bye" never happens. If I trap CTRL_C_EVENT instead and hit ^C in the console then the main thread is allowed to continue and exits gracefully. Is there some way to allow the main thread to exit gracefully on console close?

I've also tried using std::signal but it's the same. Works for ^C but not for window close.

Comment: The process is terminated as soon as your event handler returns, you don't get to override the close. So you need to do any cleanup in the event handler itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks Jonathan for the tip.

I saw that the handler is called on it's own thread. If the handler returns then the whole process is forced to exit so we need to give the main thread time to exit on its own.

```
bool done = false;

BOOL ctrl_handler(DWORD event)
{
    if (event == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT) {
        done = true;
        Sleep(20000); // force exit after 20 seconds
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler((PHANDLER_ROUTINE)(ctrl_handler), TRUE);

    while (!done)
        do_stuff();

    cleanup();
    cout << "bye";
}
```

Comment: Tried & tested tukra's answer and it works like a charm. My program terminates properly on windows and no longer segfaults on closing the console. It's ridiculous that SDL does not handle this by default and converts it into SDL_QUIT like for example terminate signals. Anyway, thank you for this solution.

Comment: If you have to use Seep suspect the solution is subpar.

Comment: This introduces a potential race condition. You did say you wanted to exit cleanly. The CRT does stuff after main returns, like call global destructors, atexit handlers, flush buffers, etc.

Comment: I updated the code to be more like what I really ended up with.

Answer (score 3):

I think the better way would be to use:

```
if (event == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT)
{
    ExitThread(0);
//  return TRUE; // warning C4702: unreachable code
}
```

The `ExitThread` will terminate the thread from which `ctrl_handler` gets called. This way `ExitProcess` will not be called, and your main thread will be able to perform all the needed cleanup.

Comment: That's a nice option. I guess it depends on specifically what you want to achieve. I looked back at the real code I ended up with related to this question and it sleeps 5 seconds and then returns, so the process will still terminate in the case the graceful exit doesn't work.

Comment: This option is somewhat up in the air. Remember each of the processes attached to the console has a new thread created in them to call their handler routines: "the system creates a new thread in the process to execute the function". It's the "system" that is orchestrating all this and exiting or terminating a thread in your process does not stop the "system" from processing the event. The question then becomes: how does the "system" handle the thread going up in a puff of smoke before it has it's answer? I can't see this behaviour described. It may not even be stable across different versions.

Comment: I tried your solution, and it works, kind of: I added "SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ctrl_handler, FALSE);" to deregister the function and with this in the code it hangs if we forcefully exit the handler thread (I'd guess it's waiting for the handler thread to finish but because we killed it it can't register its completion), so the system doesn't expect this scenario. There may be more caveats. (x86 code running on x64 version of Windows 10).

Comment: Steve, using "ExitThread" is a "hack". Of course there can be some nuances. It's logical that "SetConsoleCtrlHandler" with FALSE is not working anymore, because handler thread is dead after "ExitThread" was called. (Solution was tested on both x64 and x86 projects, Windows 10, works without any problems.)